# js проверка по нескольким ключам

Tags: javascript

есть json

```
var all = [
    {'id': 1, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.5, z: 1.5, ves: 100, v: 0.15, 'norma': 'до 15', money: 0, 'money_holiday': 100,
        wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500, dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500},
    {'id': 2, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 50, v: 0.15, 'norma': 'до 15', money: 300, 'money_holiday': 300,
        wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500, dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500},
    {'id': 3, 'x': 3, 'y': 1.7, z: 1.6, ves: 100, v: 0.4, 'norma': 'до 15', money: 300, 'money_holiday': 300,
        wait: 100, dostavka_time: 500, dostavka_nighttime: 1000, dostavka_fixnighttime: 1500}
];
```

таким образом я смогу проверить один ключ

```
for (var k in all) {
    if (all.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        for (var i in all[k]) {
            if (all[k].hasOwnProperty(i)) {

                        // alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + array[k]);

                        if (all[k][i] == '3' && i == 'x') 
                           console.log(i, all[k])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

а как сделать условие

```
if (all[k][i] == '3' && i == 'x' && all[k][i] == '1.5' && i == 'y')
```

Comment: `if (all[k][i] == '3' && i == 'x' && all[k][i] == '1.5' && i == 'y')`  не ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `i == 'x' && i == 'y'`?

Comment: @Grundy почему?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну ты сам условие посмотри :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имели ввиду, что нужно вывести в консоль элементы с ключом "x" и значением "3" и элементы с ключом "y" и значением "1.5", то нужно всего лишь заменить один оператор:

```
if (all[k][i] == '3' && i == 'x' || all[k][i] == '1.5' && i == 'y')
```